# Server-client in C: Weird behaviour when sending bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to write a server-client program in C wherein the client will send a bunch of messages in the form of 5 bytes: the first byte will contain a command, and the next four will contain a key. It looks something like this:

```
rc = write(sockfd, &op, 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        printf("error! write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
    }

    uint32_t net_num = htonl(num);
    int nsent = 0;
    while (nsent < 4)
    {
        rc = write(sockfd, &net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);
        if (rc <= 0)
        {
            printf("error! write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        nsent += rc;
    }

    if (rc <= 0)
        break;
}
```

On the receiving end, I have:

```
 while((bytes = recv(socket,buffer,5,0)) > 0)
    {
        //printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",(int)buffer[0],(int)buffer[1],      (int)buffer[2],(int)buffer[3],(int)buffer[4]);
        key = ((buffer[4] << 24) | (buffer[3] << 16) | (buffer[2] << 8) | (buffer[1]));

        if((int)buffer[0] == 0)
        {

            do command 0, etc...
```

The problem I'm having is that I cant get the key. I've tried switching the order of the shifts, but all I'm getting are numbers that don't match the keys that the client is sending. I'm at a loss.

Even stranger, is that if I compile the server without the print under the while, I get seg-faulted. If I uncomment the printf, it works fine. This seems super strange.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `&net_num + nsent,` is wrong it uses pointer arithmatic on a 32 bit type. You should first transform to a 8-bit pointer type before addition.

Comment: WRONG: `rc = write(sockfd, &net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);`.  BETTER: `rc = write(sockfd, &net_num , sizeof(net_num));`.  ALSO: how did you allocate "buffer"?  Is it large enough? Do you pass the correct buffer size?  For that matter,  why don't you simply use "&net_num" and "ntohl()" in your "recv()"?

Comment: Is there a way to fix this server-side?

Answer (score 0):

`rc = write(sockfd, &net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);` is wrong, `&net_num` is a pointer to a 32 bits object, so `&net_num+1` would point to the next 32bits object. That is beyond the object. You could cast to a char pointer, or copy to a small char buffer before sending, like below:

---

```
uint32_t net_num = htonl(num);
char buff[sizeof net_num];
memcpy (buff, &net_num, sizeof buff);

int nsent;
for nsent=0; nsent < sizeof buff; nsent += rc;)
{
    rc = write(sockfd, buff + nsent, 4 - nsent);
    if (rc == -1 && errno == EAGAIN) { rc=0; continue; }
    if (rc <= 0)
    {
        printf("error! write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I casted to a char pointer and it didn't change anything.

Comment: There could be more errors. (I read like a proofreader: I stop when I encounter the first error. Sorry!)